# Searching a List of NamedTuples for Specific Attribute

Tags: python, namedtuple

I have a list of NamedTuples (extract below) and I want to search through the list and print "Found" if an attribute of one of the tuples contains a specific string.

This is my first time using NamedTuples in a list and I cannot work out how to do it.

In the extract below I want to print "Found" if d in PassEvent == "fail". I had thought it would be as simple as:

```
if "fail" in list:
    print("Found")
```

But this does not work What am I doing wrong?

```
list = [TestEvent(a=1721, b=149, time=1638440312.0539408), TestEvent(a=1713, b=149, time=1638440312.069566), TestEvent(a=1699, b=149, time=1638440312.069566), TestEvent(a=1675, b=152, time=1638440312.0851774), TestEvent(a=1644, b=160, time=1638440312.0851774), TestEvent(a=1606, b=171, time=1638440312.1008158), TestEvent(a=1568, b=181, time=1638440312.1008158), TestEvent(a=1541, b=188, time=1638440312.116437), TestEvent(a=1499, b=193, time=1638440312.116437), TestEvent(a=1463, b=199, time=1638440312.1320653), TestEvent(a=1418, b=201, time=1638440312.1320653), TestEvent(a=1374, b=201, time=1638440312.1476848), PassEvent(f=1325, d=”fail”, t=11233)]
```

Comment: Well not really... `list` (bad name for a variable) is a list of `NamedTuple`s, not strings so there is no way such check will ever work